# How to backup WP blog posts to computer, not new site

Tags: posts, blog, backup

Can someone please help me? I have purchased a new domain which is now sharing with my previous one that is currently "parked" there. While I will be keeping some posts on the site, I am revamping most pages and thus want to download my posts to my computer so I don't lose the work. I tried exporting, but the xl file looked so convoluted and confusing. What I'd ideally like is just a text version of each post  (even if they are all together in one file) so that I can go back and copy/paste if I ever want to. I also just want to keep the writing since some of it is personal/sentimental without losing it all. Thank you in advance!

Comment: WP stores everything in the database, so if you can access your database and download a .sql file, that would allow you to have a backup of all of the text. You can open this type of file in various text editors and IDEs, such as Notepad++ or VSCode, and see the text in a fairly human-readable form.

Comment: You could also consider using the Internet Archive to manually archive each post. That way you'd be able to see the full pages exactly as they were, text, layout, and all. It's just a bit laborious as you have to paste in each URL individually.

Answer (score 0):

If you can login to the admin of your parked domain, install this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-ultimate-csv-importer/ and save the csv. You can see all of your content there.